# How to deserialize Avro message from kafka into custom C# class

Tags: c#, .net-core, apache-kafka, avro

I have a kafka consumer which consumes messages in avro format within a generic class (in order to re-use it for a few similar topics):

```
var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<string, GenericRecord>(conf)
                .SetValueDeserializer(new AvroDeserializer<GenericRecord>(schemaRegistry).AsSyncOverAsync())
                .Build()
```

Avro deserializes messages from kafka into this `GenericRecord` type

```
ConsumeResult<string, GenericRecord>? result = consumer.Consume(cancelToken.Token);
```

By accessing `result.Message.Value` I can see that it contains schema and dictionary with values. In order to use in the business logic it is required to map this value into some type from the logic layer. In order to do it there is a way of creating a custom mapper for each topic with manual mapping of each value to each property:

```
result.Message.Value.TryGetValue(nameof(prop1), out string val1)
result.Message.Value.TryGetValue(nameof(prop2), out string val2)
...
```

And other approach to is create generic mapper through reflection.

Both approaches are fine, but I wonder if there is any other way to map it directly without this manual code. I'm struggling to find a built-in solution for such obvious case.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe using [KafkaFlow](https://github.com/Farfetch/kafkaflow) typed handlers.

https://farfetch.github.io/kafkaflow/docs/guides/middlewares/typed-handler-middleware

KafkaFlow is a framework built on top of Confluent Client.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason that you have the mapper code, from what I can tell, is that you are trying to either consume multiple topics or have multiple event types in one topic.

For the case of multiple topics, start with Bytes deserializer, then run an if-statement in the processing code based on the record's Topic attribute, and manually construct and invoke the AvroDeserializer with a specific record type (generated by `avrogen`) for each topic.

Otherwise, if you have multiple event types, then you'll need some defining property within each record, such as using Kafka record headers, or a wrapper envelope (such as CloudEvents spec), which includes a `type` field, but generic `byte[] data` field that can be later deserialized, similar to above (Avro itself supports a bytes field type, so you could make easily make such a record with string + bytes fields).

The fallback option is a try-catch loop over a list of schemas that match any event in the topic. (again, starting with Bytes deserializer in the consumer config)